# Creating layer in Tensorflow with call build() method automatically

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am build a model with custom layer by using Tensorflow2 follow this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer)

I want to automatically create `input_shape` by calling `build` method when I declare a custom layer in `__init__` method.

For example:

```py
class CLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, hidden_units):
        super(CLayer, self).__init__()
        self.dense_layers = [keras.layers.Dense(u) for u in hidden_units]

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = inputs
        for layer in self.dense_layers:
            x = layer(x)
        return x

c_layer_1 = CLayer(hidden_units=[2,4])
# clayer is still call `build()` method so c_layer_1 don't have `input_shape` for each layer in c_layer_1
c_layer_1.get_weights() # return []
```

`c_layer_1.get_weights()` return a list without weights. But when I **manually** call `build()` method, it returns the layer weights as my expected.

```py
c_layer_2 = CLayer(hidden_units=[2,4])

input_arr = np.random.rand(1,2).astype(dtype=np.float32)
c_layer_2(input_arr)
c_layer_2.get_weights() 
#return [array([[ 0.30477905, -0.7402924 ],
#        [ 0.63039017,  0.33198082]], dtype=float32),
# array([0., 0.], dtype=float32),
# array([[ 0.49092817,  0.5744488 ,  0.7653606 ,  0.36842155],
#        [ 0.20108438,  0.68443155, -0.589319  , -0.92959046]],
#       dtype=float32),
# array([0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)]
```

How do I solve this problem? Thank for your helping!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
for layer in self.dense_layers:
    x = layer()(x)
```

Comment: what is `x`? and this run in `__init__` method?

Comment: Code only "answers" are considered low quality in SO.  Please add some explanation to help future visitors learn from your knowledge, and determine if it can be applied to their own coding issues.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about official solution for this problem. I treat by

```py
class CLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_units):
        super(CLayer, self).__init__()
        # self.dense_layers = [keras.layers.Dense(u) for u in hidden_units]
        _input_dim = input_dim
        for u in hidden_units:
          layer = keras.layers.Dense(u)
          layer.build(input_shape=(None,_input_dim))
          self.dense_layers.append(layer)
    
    #...
```

This will make sure the layer has weight when create it.